# how spilt this 2d array into 1d arrays

Tags: multidimensional-array

How to spilt below 2d array into 1d arrays by rows in java

```
{ {2 3 7}
  {56 43 23}
  {25 32 78}
}
```

like below

```
array1 {2 3 7}
array2 {56 43 23}
array3 {25 32 78}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use array `clone()` here:

```java
int[][] input = new int[][] { {2, 3, 7}, {56, 43, 23}, {25, 32, 78}};
int[] array1 = input[0].clone();
int[] array2 = input[1].clone();
int[] array3 = input[2].clone();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array1));  // [2, 3, 7]
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array2));  // [56, 43, 23]
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array3));  // [25, 32, 78]
```